# Mobile Azure service for iOS and Android

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am working on the project where my backend will be in Azure and it will be native iOS and Android application :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-how-to-use-client-library

My question is :-
Does Azure provide the service where we don't have to create any webservices to transfer the data between mobile and database on server?

We can handle everything from mobile side ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What, exactly, do you want to handle mobile-side: direct connections to a database? If so, there's nothing stopping you from doing that (aside from embedding all authentication details into your mobile app, which can be reverse-engineered). Please edit to clarify your question. As it stands, it'll likely be closed as 'unclear' or 'too broad'.

Answer (score 2):

NO - and you don't want that.  It opens up a massive security hole.

You have to create the App Service and then use Easy Tables.  Once the table is created, you can use the model in the client code and just push changes to the service.  It will automatically and dynamically change the model on the backend.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Does app service means webservices ? Client code means the code at iOS side i will make the client  right ?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/mobile/ios/ :- from here i can say that in azure we dont need to write code for webservice on server side. we can directly communicate to database of server by our iOS code.